# mariadb make_query stucks in make_query() call

Tags: c++, mysql, c, mariadb

mariadb version: 10.2.12-6. 
My DB query stuck in read for ever when my remote mariadb restrated (or similar action). GDB stack trace confirm the read stuck:

```
#0  0x00007fe14b46d7ad in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fe14d922935 in sock_read () from /lib64/libcrypto.so.10
#2  0x00007fe14d92099b in BIO_read () from /lib64/libcrypto.so.10
#3  0x00007fe14dc99fe4 in ssl3_read_n () from /lib64/libssl.so.10
#4  0x00007fe14dc9b87d in ssl3_read_bytes () from /lib64/libssl.so.10
#5  0x00007fe14dc98304 in ssl3_read_internal () from /lib64/libssl.so.10
#6  0x00007fe14e11eb6d in ma_tls_read () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#7  0x00007fe14e10dd91 in ma_pvio_read () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#8  0x00007fe14e10dff3 in ma_pvio_cache_read () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#9  0x00007fe14e1041be in ma_real_read () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#10 0x00007fe14e104fdc in ma_net_read () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#11 0x00007fe14e109d5e in ma_net_safe_read () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#12 0x00007fe14e10cfe5 in mthd_my_read_query_result () from /lib64/libmysqlclient.so.18
#13 0x00007fe14e563987 in make_query (
    query=0x7fe128ff8500 "update heartbeat set .........") at *****:2600
#14 0x000000000041691d in *******(short, unsigned char*) ()
#15 0x0000000000415761 in *******(void*) ()
#16 0x00007fe14b466dd5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#17 0x00007fe14b190b3d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

I tried to find if there is any method where I can put timeout in make_query() call for mysql/mariadb but couldnt find any. 
Anyone knows how can we configure make_query() for a timeout?

Note: programming language used is C, C++

Answer (score 0):

You could call this method from a new child thread and let parent thread wait on the  it until timeout or parent could kill it if it doesn't return in time. Not a clean way but would resolve your problem. In fact, you could abstract this mechanism such that when there'd an update to mariadb in the future, you could just remove the helper child thread.

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB, see `max_statement_time` and other techniques [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/query-limits-and-timeouts/)

(Many of the things mentioned there are not available with MySQL.)